# How to parse JSON in node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, express

I'm using the API's node wrapper: https://github.com/MySportsFeeds/mysportsfeeds-node/blob/master/README.md
https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/data-feeds/api-docs#

The call is going through fine and automatically saving on under "/results"

Here's my code:

```
 msf.authenticate("username", "password");
    var data = msf.getData('nba', '2016-2017-regular', 'cumulative_player_stats', 'json', {
        player: 'nick-young'
    });

    request(data, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(parsedData["cumulativeplayerstats"]["playerstatsentry"][0]["stats"]["PtsPerGame"]["#text"]);
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: JSON.parse(obj)

Comment: _"How to parse JSON in node js"_.... you are already doing it `JSON.parse(body)` if `body` is the actual JSON text response. If you are having a problem you should say what the actual problem is, and any error messages you might be receiving

Comment: have you console log error to make sure you arent getting an error? Did you console log just parseData to make sure it was parsed correctly? Did you console log body to make sure it is what you think it is?

Comment: I updated my question to the what is showing up in the console. JSON is saving in results folder. Do I need to get the JSON from the results folder then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call **msf.getData**(league, season, feed, format, and any other applicable params for the feed) with format 'json'. It return a json object. As a result your **data** will be a json object.

```
msf.authenticate("username", "password");
var data = msf.getData('nba', '2016-2017-regular', 'cumulative_player_stats', 'json', {player: 'nick-young'});

console.log(data["cumulativeplayerstats"]["playerstatsentry"][0]["stats"]["PtsPerGame"]["#text"]);
```

Read json file content using fs.readFile

**Sync**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('results/cumulative_player_stats-nba-2016-2017-regular.json', 'utf8'));
```

**Async**

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('results/cumulative_player_stats-nba-2016-2017-regular.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  const json = JSON.parse(data);

  console.log(json["cumulativeplayerstats"]["playerstatsentry"][0]["stats"]["PtsPerGame"]["#text"]);
});
```

Comment: The console says this with and without console.log : File saved as 'results/cumulative_player_stats-nba-2016-2017-regular.json'.

How can I parse that JSON file?

Comment: Question on the async code. I'm getting an error on the const json; line. How can I get that resolved?